# Arranging nested lists in python

Tags: python, list

Consider the following list in python:

```
[[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]],
 [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']],
 [[21, 22], [23, 24], [25, 26], [27, 28]]]
```

The top level list contains 3 list values which in-turn consists of 4 individual lists.
I need to arrange these this lists in the following order:

```
[[1, 2, 'a', 'b', 21, 22],
 [3, 4, 'c', 'd', 23, 24],
 [5, 6, 'e', 'f', 25, 26],
 [7, 8, 'g', 'h', 27, 28]]
```

I have tried to implement this requirement using itertools, for loops, list comprehension etc but was unable to get it. Could you provide me the necessary python code capable of doing this requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `zip()` here, then flatten out the resulting tuples with sublists:

```
[[i for sub in combo for i in sub] for combo in zip(*inputlist)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> inputlist = [[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]],
...  [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']],
...  [[21, 22], [23, 24], [25, 26], [27, 28]]]
>>> [[i for sub in combo for i in sub] for combo in zip(*inputlist)]
[[1, 2, 'a', 'b', 21, 22], [3, 4, 'c', 'd', 23, 24], [5, 6, 'e', 'f', 25, 26], [7, 8, 'g', 'h', 27, 28]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) with `map`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, izip, starmap
>>> map(list, starmap(chain, izip(*lst)))
[[1, 2, 'a', 'b', 21, 22],
 [3, 4, 'c', 'd', 23, 24],
 [5, 6, 'e', 'f', 25, 26],
 [7, 8, 'g', 'h', 27, 28]]
```